# pandas : convert single index from hierarchical_index to series to allow computations on index values

Tags: pandas

Is there a way of converting a single  index ( from hierarchical index) as a series?

Use case : group by year and month (so year and month form hierarchical index) then create new column by combining year and month ( or performing some other operation that requires a series rather than index)

I know I could use reset_index() but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
daily = pd.DataFrame({'Low': {pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'): 14.15, pd.Timestamp('2000-02-01 00:00:00'): 13.9, pd.Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): 19.140000000000001, pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 23.620000000000001}})

df = daily.groupby([daily.index.year, daily.index.month]).first()
print df
          Low
2000 1  14.15
     2  13.90
2016 1  23.62
     2  19.14

print df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[2000, 2016], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

print df.index.get_level_values(0)
Int64Index([2000, 2000, 2016, 2016], dtype='int64')

print df.index.get_level_values(1)
Int64Index([1, 2, 1, 2], dtype='int64')

print df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()
2000    2000
2000    2000
2016    2016
2016    2016
dtype: int64

df['month'] = df.index.get_level_values(1)
print df[['Low','month']]
          Low  month
2000 1  14.15      1
     2  13.90      2
2016 1  23.62      1
     2  19.14      2
```